Moser-Trudinger inequality for surfaces of non-negative Gaussian curvature
Let $(\Sigma,g)$ be a compact Riemannian surface without boundary. The classical Moser Trudinger inequality implies that there exists constants $\beta,C$ depending on $M,g$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_M e^{\beta u^2}dv_g\leq C_1
\end{equation}
for all $u$ satisfying $\int_M|\nabla u|^2dv_g\leq 1$ and $\int_Mudv_g=0$. Consequently, for $u\in H^1(M)$ there exists a constant $\eta,C_2$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_M e^{u}dv_g\leq C_2\exp(\eta \|\nabla u\|^2_2+\frac{1}{Vol(M)}\int_Mudv_g)
\end{equation}
Now suppose $(M,g)$ has non-negative Gaussian curvature and bounded diameter, can the constants $\eta, C_2$ in the second inequality be chosen to be universal?
Thanks in advance for an!
